# Site give different response when request sent by jQuery jPlayer

Tags: jquery, jplayer

I am trying to use jQuery jPlayer (downloaded 2.5.0 demo, using circle player) to play a remote link `http://data10.5sing.com/T1T5VTB4ET1R47IVrK.mp3`, the link can be played in a browser, or using `wget` to download, in these cases the server responded 200 OK. However if I play it using the following code, the server responded 403 Forbidden, why is that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />

    <!-- Website Design By: www.happyworm.com -->
    <title>Demo : jPlayer circle player</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/skin/circle.skin/circle.player.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.transform2d.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.grab.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/mod.csstransforms.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/circle.player.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     //<![CDATA[

     $(document).ready(function(){

       /*
    * Instance CirclePlayer inside jQuery doc ready
    *
    * CirclePlayer(jPlayerSelector, media, options)
    *   jPlayerSelector: String - The css selector of the jPlayer div.
    *   media: Object - The media object used in jPlayer("setMedia",media).
    *   options: Object - The jPlayer options.
    *
    * Multiple instances must set the cssSelectorAncestor in the jPlayer options. Defaults to "#cp_container_1" in CirclePlayer.
    *
    * The CirclePlayer uses the default supplied:"m4a, oga" if not given, which is different from the jPlayer default of supplied:"mp3"
    * Note that the {wmode:"window"} option is set to ensure playback in Firefox 3.6 with the Flash solution.
    * However, the OGA format would be used in this case with the HTML solution.
    */

       var myCirclePlayer = new CirclePlayer("#jquery_jplayer_1",
                         {
       mp3: "http://data10.5sing.com/T1T5VTB4ET1R47IVrK.mp3"
     }, {
       cssSelectorAncestor: "#cp_container_1",
       swfPath: "js",
       supplied: "mp3",
       wmode: "window",
       keyEnabled: true
     });
     });
     //]]>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- The jPlayer div must not be hidden. Keep it at the root of the body element to avoid any such problems. -->
    <div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="cp-jplayer"></div>

    <!-- The container for the interface can go where you want to display it. Show and hide it as you need. -->

    <div id="cp_container_1" class="cp-container">
      <div class="cp-buffer-holder"> <!-- .cp-gt50 only needed when buffer is > than 50% -->
    <div class="cp-buffer-1"></div>
    <div class="cp-buffer-2"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="cp-progress-holder"> <!-- .cp-gt50 only needed when progress is > than 50% -->
    <div class="cp-progress-1"></div>
    <div class="cp-progress-2"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="cp-circle-control"></div>
      <ul class="cp-controls">
    <li><a class="cp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
    <li><a class="cp-pause" style="display:none;" tabindex="1">pause</a></li> <!-- Needs the inline style here, or jQuery.show() uses display:inline instead of display:block -->
      </ul>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Because it's trying to use the Flash player and the remote site hasn't allowed remote access by Flash objects, perhaps?  I'm unfortunately not terribly familiar with HTML5 cross-site access rules.

Comment: @Crontab No, my code is not using Flash player. Also I have tried to embed the same link in a flash player and no problem.

Comment: jPlayer will fall back to Flash if it can't create the HTML5 interface in your browser, that is how they wrote it.  It doesn't have much to do with the settings you use.